# Videos should appear on same page after after going back to previous page

Tags: javascript

In the code I am working on, the video is not reappearing after it is removed, why is this, and is there a way for that to be fixed or adjusted in the code so that the videos will appear after going back to a previous page?

To reproduce, click on a button to enter a container, then the blue play button, then the exit button, then enter the same button again, the video has not reappeared.

code https://jsfiddle.net/wzaknd08/

```
  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    let container = el.closest(".container");
    let wrappers;
    if (container) { //if multiple players
      wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".remove .wrap");
    } else { //if single player
      container = el.closest(".remove");
      wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    }
    wrappers.forEach(function (wrapper) {
      if (wrapper.player) {
        removePlayer(wrapper);
      }
    });
  }
```

In the **demo code** here click on the same play button multiple times.

You will see the video stays reappearing.

https://jsfiddle.net/g1ztucmp/

How would that be fixed in the code I am working on so that the videos appear again after going back to view the same videos after they are removed.

Like how it works in the demo code I provided.

Comment: I do not have time to write a proper answer right now. However, you are adding the .active class in the showCover function (line 68), but it's not being removed from it when you close the video.

Comment: Is there a way for me to fix that? is there a piece of code from the demo code I would need to add to my code to fix that?

Comment: Just found some time. Added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding a class to wrap called active when you press the play button.

```
function showCover(playButton) {
   const cover = playButton.parentElement;
   cover.classList.add("active");
 }
```

However, you never remove that class when closing the player(s). So when closing the player you need to remove the active class again. This is best done in the removePlayer function as you already iterate though al the classes that might have them.

```
function removePlayer(wrapper) {
    wrapper.player.destroy();
    wrapper.classList.remove("active");
    delete wrapper.player;
    console.log("removePlayer");
```

}

Change you Fiddle to make it work: https://jsfiddle.net/wqchdey1/. Only change was me adding `wrapper.classList.remove("active");` to the removePlayer function